# Excel Logic and If Statements

Tags: excel, logic

I am trying to do write a nested if statement that does the following:

IF C19 = No, C20 = No, and C22 = Yes then C30 = No

else

IF C19 = Yes or C20 = Yes and C22 = Yes then C30 = Yes

So far I have the following (Non-working) code:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C19="No",C20="No",C22="Yes"), C22="Yes","Yes","No"))
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have some other permutations missing, making the whole statement unfinished. Also, group your logic for point two. Is it ((C19=Yes OR C20=Yes) AND C22 = Yes), or it is ((C19=Yes OR (C20=Yes AND C22=Yes)

Comment: Thanks Psychic for the advice, some permutations are missing but I am fairly certain they need not be handled. It is ((C19=Yes OR C20=Yes) AND C22 = Yes) then C30 = Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this to cater for

- the common test `C30="Yes"` **not** being met (ie giving `"C22<>Yes"`)
- both paired tests for C19 amd C20 **not** being met (ie giving `"C19 and/or C20 are invalid"`
- your two desired outcomes for C30  (either `Yes` or `No`)

*Update:* seeing Nick's answer made me realise that you did have an Or test in your second test

> =IF(C22="Yes",IF(AND(C19 ="No",C20 ="No"),"No",IF(OR(C19 ="Yes",C20 ="Yes"),"Yes","C19 and/or C20 are invalid")),"C22<>Yes")

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that if they don't match either of these conditions then do nothing, then this should work

```
=IF(AND(OR(C19="Yes",C20="Yes"),C22="Yes"),"Yes",IF(AND(C19="No",C20="No",C22="Yes"),"No",""))
```

Comment: +1 for first correct answer although I do recommend flagging what portion hasn't given the expected result rather than a "" catchall

Answer (score 0):

The IF statement needs to have a logical test, with two values, one to return if the test is true, the other if the test was false.

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

You can however, expand on this by embedding subsequent IF statements within one or both of the values, and this can recurse. eg:

IF(logical_test, (IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])), ([value_if_false]))

Each step of the recursion is still a simple boolean (true/false) test, with two possible answers.

Once you boil down the conditions you have to meet into simple true/false statements, just insert them into the IF statement.